# ErrImagePull in microk8s

Tags: kubernetes

I am reading the book "Microservices in .NET second edition". In the third chapter of the book the author tries to set up a microk8s cluster on localhost to host a web service. The code for the configuration of the Kubernetes is this:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: shopping-cart
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: shopping-cart
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: shopping-cart
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: shopping-cart
          image: your_unique_registry_name.azurecr.io/shopping-cart:1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: shopping-cart
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: shopping-cart
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: shopping-cart
```

I issue the command
`kubectl apply -f shopping-cart.yaml`
When I do
`kubectl get all` to see if everything runs well I get the following output:

```
NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/shopping-cart-784b775b94-v5ddl   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          25m
pod/shopping-cart-6bd7897fd5-bnlvh   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          36m

NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP          13d
service/shopping-cart   LoadBalancer   10.152.183.254   <pending>     5000:32238/TCP   36m

NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/shopping-cart   0/1     1            0           36m

NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/shopping-cart-6bd7897fd5   1         1         0       36m
replicaset.apps/shopping-cart-784b775b94   1         1         0       25m
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?
The full code of the book is on https://github.com/horsdal/microservices-in-dotnet-book-second-edition look for chapter 3.
I use Manjaro linux for development and .NET 7, the book is written for .NET 5. Also although it says ImagePullBackOff eventually it becomes ErrImagePull as the title of the post says.

I also want to add the following output:

```
kubectl describe pod shopping-cart                      INT ✘ 
Name:             shopping-cart-784b775b94-v5ddl
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             dso-z68xud5b3/192.168.1.9
Start Time:       Sat, 31 Dec 2022 11:37:04 +0200
Labels:           app=shopping-cart
                  pod-template-hash=784b775b94
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 2f73bffa63650fc7bf3497b7255172f8d80f7834de0a7e2738e26579006261c2
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.1.59.225/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.1.59.225/32
Status:           Pending
IP:               10.1.59.225
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.59.225
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/shopping-cart-784b775b94
Containers:
  shopping-cart:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          your_unique_registry_name.azurecr.io/shopping-cart:1.0.0
    Image ID:       
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-6cghz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-6cghz:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------             ----                  ----     -------
  Warning  MissingClusterDNS  3m32s (x71 over 18m)  kubelet  pod: "shopping-cart-784b775b94-v5ddl_default(1e24b5d3-d921-45a1-b5ec-2edc35e651e4)". kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to "Default" policy.

Name:             shopping-cart-6bd7897fd5-bnlvh
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             dso-z68xud5b3/192.168.1.9
Start Time:       Sat, 31 Dec 2022 11:26:03 +0200
Labels:           app=shopping-cart
                  pod-template-hash=6bd7897fd5
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: a859a48851ce4eecb8311318cc71b6057fab2ad2c74e5e41b1bff419d3f210ae
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.1.59.224/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.1.59.224/32
Status:           Pending
IP:               10.1.59.224
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.59.224
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/shopping-cart-6bd7897fd5
Containers:
  shopping-cart:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          shopping-cart
    Image ID:       
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-hcmnb (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-hcmnb:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------             ----                  ----     -------
  Warning  MissingClusterDNS  3m24s (x71 over 18m)  kubelet  pod: "shopping-cart-6bd7897fd5-bnlvh_default(5309b220-a258-4930-bf64-9b1cf0cbafc7)". kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to "Default" policy.
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You did actually replace `your_unique_registry_name.azurecr.io` with the address of the Azure Container Registry (or any other Docker registry) you created, yes?

Comment: @DanielB the name property is "shopping-cart" on my local machine.

Comment: Let me rephrase that then: Does the _fully qualified_ image name point to a location that can be pulled? Ie. when doing `docker pull` with the _exact_ same image name (ideally on the same PC), does that work? From K8s docs: “If you don't specify a registry hostname, Kubernetes assumes that you mean the Docker public registry.”

Comment: docker pull shopping-cart
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for shopping-cart, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: you'll have to setup authentication for the registraty as the error message says: for docker pull, use `docker login your_unique_registry_name.azurecr.io`. For Kube to pull the image, setup image pull secrets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what’s in the book, but the repository has all the ingredients needed. You may have skipped some steps. You need the following:

- A Docker image (called `your_unique_registry_name.azurecr.io/shopping-cart:1.0.0` in the *template* YAML)
- A container registry (called `your_unique_registry_name.azurecr.io` in the *template* YAML)
- (A Kubernetes cluster)

The repository contains a [*template* script](https://github.com/horsdal/microservices-in-dotnet-book-second-edition/blob/main/Chapter03/create-aks.ps1) for creating *both* a container registry (ACR) and a Kubernetes cluster (AKS) on the Microsoft Azure cloud. *Alternatively*, any other registry (and K8s) will do, even Docker Hub! You can also [enable the built-in container registry in MicroK8s](https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-built-in).

The relevant code to create the container registry on Azure is as follows:

```
az group create --name MicroservicesInDotnet --location northeurope
az acr create --resource-group MicroservicesInDotnet --name YOUR_UNIQUE_REGISTRY_NAME --sku Basic
```

These commands require the Azure CLI be installed.

To enable the MicroK8s container registry, use this command, then [follow the documentation](https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-built-in):

```
microk8s enable registry
```

The repository also contains a [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/horsdal/microservices-in-dotnet-book-second-edition/blob/main/Chapter03/Dockerfile) for creating the Docker image that is to be used inside the Kubernetes cluster. After creating the image locally (using `docker build` with appropriate parameters), you must then push it (`docker push`) to the registry you want to use.

Whatever way you chose, it is important to use the exact name of the image (including the part after the colon!) in your Kubernetes YAML file. If you can `docker pull` this name, it’ll most likely work in Kubernetes. If you cannot, it almost certainly will not work.

If the registry you decided on is only accessible with credentials (often called “private”, needs `docker login`), Kubernetes also needs those to pull the image. From the [documentation on pulling from private registries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/), the way to go with username/email/password authentication is:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

If your registry uses a different authentication scheme, things are more complicated, but the guide offers solutions. The result is a cluster secret called `regcred`. You can reference this secret in the deployment YAML:

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: shopping-cart
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: shopping-cart
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: shopping-cart
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets: # <--
        - name: regcred # <--
      containers:
        - name: shopping-cart
          image: your_unique_registry_name.azurecr.io/shopping-cart:1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: You missed mentioning setting up the image pull resecrets, which is the most probable cause for the image pull to fail

Comment: I didn't miss a step from the book. The book missed to write all those nice things you wrote about the built-in registry of microk8s and also that I have to push the image to a registry. Thanks for your answer. Now I dropped this book and I am reading another "The Kubernetes Book 2022".

Comment: @SathyajithBhat While not the case here, it is important anyway. I extended the answer with a section on that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It just makes it a pretty comprehensive answer.